# Appending a column to large csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bigdata

I have uploaded a large csv into python using the following code:

```
ddgqa = pd.read_table("/Users/xxxx/Documents/globalqa-pageurls-Report.csv", chunksize= 10**6, iterator=True)
```

I am now extract a column into a dataframe using this code:

```
for chunk in ddgqa:
    links_adobe_ddgqa = pd.DataFrame(ddga['Page URL'])
```

When I try to `links_adobe_ddgqa`

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-1ab6eaf23d5f> in <module>()
----> 1 links_adobe_ddgqa

NameError: name 'links_adobe_ddgqa' is not defined
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is `links_adobe_ddgqa` defined? If it's only defined in your loop then it goes out of scope outside the loop, you need to declare it outside the `for` loop

Comment: it is not defined. I assumed I could define it like this. When i set links_adobe_ddgqa = [ ] and run the for loop , it doesnt seem to work. When i call links_adobe_ddgqa it returns []!

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? for instance it's unclear why you're trying to create a df from a single column in a chunk of your df. You can just read a single column by passing `usecols=['Page URL']` to `pd.read_table` you can then just append the chunks

Comment: Are you suggesting to use read_table instead of read csv? I tried this with csv and it gave me Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Page URL,"Page Views"]
Index: []

Comment: I'm saying that all you seem to be doing is just chunking a specific column, `read_table` and `read_csv` both support importing a specific column see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table)

Comment: Thanks alot Ed. I am having a dumb day so please be patient. When I add usecols=['Page URL'] and try to print the chunk, why does it give me an empty data frame?

Comment: Because your column name doesn't match read a single line from the file and print `ddgqa.columns.tolist()`, you may have leading/trailing spaces or it maybe be different case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148061/discussion-between-data-kid-and-edchum).